# Is there any way to identify passwords in my keychains that haven't been accessed in a long time?

Tags: keychain

I'm a web developer and I deal with a lot of passwords. Many of these I only need for a short while and then never again. My login keychain has quickly grown to several hundred items. I do the occasional spring clean, but it's tedious.

What would be incredibly useful is if I could see the last time each password was read. Anything that hadn't been touched in say three months would be a good candidate for deletion. I might even be able to automate the process, moving old passwords into a "trash" keychain.

I've played around with the `security` terminal command and it looks like only creation and modification times are recorded. Is that right?

Comment: I have often wondered the same thing, especially when scrolling through my iCloud keychain looking for a password and getting to the right one only to see there are 10 entries which I have to try one at a time, typing in my keychain password for each try.

Comment: Another thing - I think that Apple Mail tries expired entries that don't get deleted.  The reason I'm visiting this question is to find out how to read the item info in bulk.